# A true heat map in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'd like to make a true heat map in R, much like a weather map, except my data is much more simple.

Consider this 3d data:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
z <- rnorm(20)
```

The z would be color.

Here is what a discrete looking heatmap would like for this data:
[image]

How can I make a heatmap such that the colors are smooth and the full 2d space is filled with smoothed out colors based on the z values.

Please include sample code, not just a link that will probably confuse me even more, and I've probably already visited that site anyhow. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any way I can get this color scheme in the default packages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following:

`interp` in the `akima` package

`image.plot` in the `fields` package

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
z <- rnorm(20)

library(fields)
library(akima)

s <- interp(x,y,z)
image.plot(s)
```

Comment: Another plotting option is to use the geom_tile geometry from ggplot2.

Answer (score 2):

`smooth.2d` in the `fields` package does a good job (and it is much faster than `interp` from `akima` package for larger number of input points.

```
library(fields)

x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
z <- rnorm(20)

s = smooth.2d(z, x=cbind(x,y), theta=0.5)
image.plot(s)
```