# R alternative to smoothscatter plot but with colour palette for 3rd dimension?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to have a plot in R similar to the 2D smoothScatter plot, but with an extra dimension using something like a palette of different colours or a surface. Is this possible with any package?

Example:

```
x = rnorm(1000)
y = rnorm(1000,10)
z = rnorm(1000,5)
smoothScatter(x,y)

somemagicmethod(x,y,z)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A true heat map in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421536/a-true-heat-map-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(fields)
library(akima)

s <- interp(x,y,z)
image.plot(s)
```