# How to make a heatmap in R with xyz dissimilar data

Tags: r, graph, gnuplot, heatmap

I am trying to use the [A true heat map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421536/a-true-heat-map-in-r) suggestions, however I get the error:

> Error in interp.old(x, y, z, xo = xo, yo = yo, ncp = 0, extrap = extrap,
>       : scales of x and y are too dissimilar

after the code line:

```
 s <- interp(x,y,z)
```

My data was constructed expecting to get coloured heat-map like lines in a dark continuous background, and works in `GNUplot` using `set pm3d map` and `set hidden3d`. The data corresponds to a model of molecules production (`y`) in a given time (`x`) with the frequency of appearance denoted by `z`. It looks like this:

```
1.000000000000e+00  1e-8    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-8    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-7    5

1.000000000000e+00  5e-7    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-6    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-6    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-5    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-5    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-4    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-4    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-3    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-3    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-2    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-2    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e-1    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e-1    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+1    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+1    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+2    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+2    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+3    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+3    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+4    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+4    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+5    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+5    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+6    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+6    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+7    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+7    0

1.000000000000e+00  1e+8    0

1.000000000000e+00  5e+8    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-8    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-8    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-7    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-7    5

2.000000000000e+00  1e-6    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-6    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-5    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-5    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-4    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-4    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-3    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-3    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-2    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-2    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e-1    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e-1    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+1    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+1    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+2    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+2    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+3    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+3    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+4    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+4    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+5    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+5    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+6    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+6    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+7    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+7    0

2.000000000000e+00  1e+8    0

2.000000000000e+00  5e+8    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-8    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-8    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-7    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-7    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-6    5

3.000000000000e+00  5e-6    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-5    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-5    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-4    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-4    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-3    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-3    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-2    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-2    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e-1    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e-1    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+1    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+1    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+2    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+2    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+3    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+3    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+4    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+4    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+5    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+5    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+6    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+6    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+7    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+7    0

3.000000000000e+00  1e+8    0

3.000000000000e+00  5e+8    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-8    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-8    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-7    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-7    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-6    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-6    5

4.000000000000e+00  1e-5    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-5    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-4    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-4    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-3    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-3    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-2    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-2    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e-1    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e-1    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+1    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+1    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+2    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+2    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+3    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+3    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+4    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+4    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+5    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+5    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+6    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+6    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+7    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+7    0

4.000000000000e+00  1e+8    0

4.000000000000e+00  5e+8    0
```

The first suggestion gave me some ugly results similar the ones obtained at first in [A true heat map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421536/a-true-heat-map-in-r) which is a plot with some horizontal lines full of dots in different gray-scale tones. The second seems to crash. I got this message from it:

```
>Traceback:
1: .Fortran("idsfft", as.integer(1), as.integer(ncp), as.integer(n),     as.double(x),  as.double(y), as.double(z), as.integer(nx),     as.integer(ny), x = as.double(xo), y = as.double(yo), z = zo,     integer((31 + ncp) * n + nx * ny), double(5 * n), misso = as.logical(misso),     PACKAGE = "akima")
2: interp.old(x, y, z, xo = xo, yo = yo, ncp = 0, extrap = extrap,     duplicate = duplicate, dupfun = dupfun)
3: interp(x, y, z)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

I just included more data in case it is helpful.
I am calling the columns from the data frame this way:

> coso <- read.table("/home/libertad/mygraphs/two/two_1_90/coso.txt", header = FALSE,sep = "\t")

```
>x <-coso[[1]]

>y <-coso[[2]]
```

This is one of my graphs in GNUplot, I expected to get nicer ones with R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Suggested Solution

Use `scale()` to transform x and y to comparable scales.

### Simulation

Using the `fields` package as in your question:

```
library(akima) 
library(fields) 

x <- rnorm(20, 4, 3)
y <- rnorm(20, 5e-5, 1e-5)
x <- scale(x) # comment out these two lines 
y <- scale(y) # to reproduce your error
z <- rnorm(20)

s <- interp(x,y,z)
image.plot(s)
```

Using `ggplot2`, adapted from [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10860335/1290420):

```
library(akima) 
library(ggplot2) 

x <- rnorm(20, 4, 3)
y <- rnorm(20, 5e-5, 1e-5)
x <- scale(x) # comment out these two lines 
y <- scale(y) # to reproduce your error
z <- rnorm(20)

t. <- interp(x,y,z)
t.df <- data.frame(t.)

gt <- data.frame( expand.grid(X1=t.$x, 
                              X2=t.$y), 
                  z=c(t.$z), 
                  value=cut(c(t.$z), 
                            breaks=seq(min(z),max(z),0.25)))

p <- ggplot(gt) + 
    geom_tile(aes(X1,X2,fill=value)) + 
    geom_contour(aes(x=X1,y=X2,z=z), colour="black") 
p
```

### Correcting the Axis Labels

In another question, the solution is also described for [labeling the axes with the correct values of the original data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861278/1290420) before the re-scaling. This currently only applies to `ggplot`.

Comment: I have some problems with gauden's suggestion. I included them in my original question.