# How can I get a certain colorful scale in R?

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I want to use a color scale that seems somewhat common (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421536/a-true-heat-map-in-r) and [here](http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/sf_eta_heatmap2-png-1.jpg)), but I couldn't find it anywhere. It's not rainbow() or heat.colors() or any other [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/palettes.html); and http://colorbrewer2.org/ also don't display it (or at least I couldn't find it). Any help, please? If it's in the basic packages, yet better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like [Matlab's Jet colours](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html), they are replicated in `?colorRampPalette`:

```
## 'jet.colors' is "as in Matlab"
## (and hurting the eyes by over-saturation)
jet.colors <-
  colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", "cyan",
                     "#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))
```

And an example:

```
filled.contour(volcano, color = jet.colors, asp = 1, nlevels=100)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `rich.colors` from `gplots` for the first link, and contrary to your post, `RColorBrewer` `"spectral"` palette for the second link, or even the palette that is designed to ape the default matlab colour palette, which is `blue2green2red` from `colorRamps`?

```
require( gplots )
barplot( rep(1,100), width = rep(2,100) , col=rich.colors(100), space = 0 , border=0, axes=FALSE)

require( RColorBrewer )
display.brewer.pal(11 , "Spectral" )

require( colorRamps )
image(matrix(1:400, 20), col = blue2green2red(400) , axes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Simon! I'll keep with the other since it doesn't need an external library, though.