# How to set the color manually in gg plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to set the color manually for the ggplot.I want it to be in a rainbow but I'm unable to do. Additionally I want to change the scale value as well. Picture is attached as a reference that what actually I;m looking for.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Here below are my code for ggplot

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Timepoint, 
                 color = Cellno,
                 y = scale(Nuclear_Foxm1_Intensity))) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 256, alpha = 0.5, 
               position="identity") + 
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 3)) + 
geom_density_2d_filled() + 
ggtitle("Control")
```

[image]

Thank You

[image: Scale and color something like that]

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-the-new-turbo-palette-from-google-in-r-af19b9424cc0

Comment: You might want something like the `stat_density_2d(
  geom = "raster",...` example near the bottom here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360829/13210554