# Gnuplot heatmap XYZ

Tags: dictionary, colors, gnuplot

Hey guys I'm trying to do a real heat map like in    [A true heat map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421536/a-true-heat-map-in-r), but in GNUPLOT.

My file is like

```
3 1 2
3 4 3
3 5 5

4 1 7
4 1 2
4 4 3
4 5 2

5 1 3
5 1 2
5 4 3

.
..
....
```

and I've tried with

plot "file" using 1:2:3 with image

splot "file" using 1:2:3 p3md

etc..

Also I follow this example http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html, but nothing.

Can someone shed some light here please?

Thanks

Comment: some examples in here http://www.kleerekoper.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-create-heatmap-in-gnuplot.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set pm3d interpolate 2,2
splot "file"
```

You can adjust level of interpolation by changing the number or even set it as 0 to tell gnuplot to "guess" it. It is not well documented what interpolation method that gnuplot is using, so be careful.

```
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
splot "file"
```

Here's the result without interpolation:

[image: no interpolation]

Here's the result with interpolation 2,2:

[image: set pm3d interpolate 2,2]

Here's the result with interpolation 0,0:

[image: set pm3d interpolate 0,0]

Comment: I think you should also add "set dgrid3d"

Comment: You may want to check this http://hirophysics.com/gnuplot/gnuplot10.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the pm3d option:

```
set pm3d
splot "file"
```

Comment: I get this:
 Warning: Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.
    Hint: Missing blank lines in the data file? See 'help pm3d' and FAQ.
Floating point exception (core dumped)