# create heatmap of 3 list using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have 3 Python list: `x = [x0, x1, x2, ..., xn]`, `y = [y0, y1, y2, ..., yn]` and `v = [v0, v1, v2, ..., vn]` and what I need to do it to visualize the data by creating a heatmap, where at coordinate `(x[k], y[k])`, value `v[k]` is visualized, the result could be something like the result in [GnuPlot Heatmap XYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663358/gnuplot-heatmap-xyz). Due to system constrain I cannot use other 3rd-party tools except numpy and matplotlib.

I've found some related topic ([Heatmap in matplotlib with pcolor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391959/heatmap-in-matplotlib-with-pcolor), [Generate a heatmap in MatPlotLib using a scatter data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set)) but it seems not resolved the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the encoded matrix is not too large for memory, it can easily be converted to a dense numpy array using array slicing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 0]
y = [0, 1]
v = [2, 3]

M = np.zeros((max(x) + 1, max(y) + 1))
M[x, y] = v

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.matshow(M)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I would add that you should look into `imshow` (not sure if `matshow` does colorbars, but if so then use that) and adding a color bar. Check out [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html)

Comment: Thanks cel! But this may lose all the coordinate information. And  the data of x, y, z may not be integers.

Comment: @WonderHAO, oh in that case you probably have to first discretize your data into bins. For that `numpy.digitize` will come in handy. Then you just sum up the z scores in each bin and plot the matrix you get with `imshow`.