# Plot heatmap from points in R

Tags: r, charts, heatmap

I want to plot a heatmap in R from a set of points.

I have a data frame like

```
X  Y  col
1  2  1
1  1  4
2  4  9
.......
```

I want to have a heatmap from this, with X and Y being the coordinates of the point, and col can be from 0 to 40. I tried to plot in points or using melt(), but with no luck.

I can plot some points with geom_point(), but I'd like to have a smooth transition from one color to another, some probably this is not the reight thing to do.

Comment: I think this question is closely related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421536/a-true-heat-map-in-r).

Comment: If there is a smooth transition, then it's NOT a heatmap. I think you need to get some statistical advice.

Comment: It is a continuous heatmap. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531059/creating-a-continuous-heat-map-in-r

Answer (score 6):

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(1:50, 1:50))
df$col <- sample(0:40, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, colour = col, fill = col )) + 
  geom_tile()
```

produces:

[image]

**Edit:**

And this

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(1:50, 1:50))
df$col <- sample(0:40, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), nrow(df) * .2, replace = FALSE), ]  # make holes
df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$col), -3]
ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..), geom = "tile", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red")
```

produces

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I don't have all the points, and thus I get some white areas which I don't want.

Comment: And what do you want? I mean, it's obvious that you got holes if you matrix is incomplete... :)

Comment: I want that the colours interpolate. So if I have a white tile next to a let's say red tile, I want the white tile to be a lighter red.

Comment: @lbedogni Why don't you then replace NAs in your data by actually interpolating?

Comment: Because I thought there would have been a proper method instead of doing it manually.